# How can I color specific cells in R Markdown table depending on their values?

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I want to color cells of a table in R Markdown depending on their value: Every cell with a value > 0 should be light blue and the cell with the largest value in the row should be a darker blue. 
At the moment I'm using the following code for the table:

```
kable(mydata) %>%
    kable_styling(bootstrap_options=c("hover", "condensed")) %>%
    column_spec(1, bold = T, border_right = T)
```

Does anyone know how I can color particular cells?

Comment: Please include all external packages that you're using and example dataset

Comment: Have a look at kableExtra - page 11 on this guide: https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the `conditional Logic` section in `Cell/Text Specification` unit  on [this page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html)

You will be able to modify cell something like this :

```
cell_spec(df, color = ifelse(df> 20, "red", "blue"))
```